# Can't click on links when in mobile mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't click on images on frontpage and on links below them when I'm in xs(extra small) mode.
Can't figure it out why. Other links are working.

Link is http://www.pippion.com/wordpress

EDIT:
I figured it out it is because wrapper has col-xs-12 class. When I remove it, it works. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today.  Turns out you need to call out all the view sizes if you use images as links.  For example if I had

```
<div class='contents col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8'>
  <a href="#something"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></a>
</div>
```

I need to make sure I call it out for mobile with xs, tablet with sm, and web with md.  That should solve your problem and not force you to remove your col-xs-12 class.